# javascript google spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

Добрый день. Задача следующая:
- Есть источник данных в гугл таблице с содержанием городов и информации по ним (города в колонке B:B, формула importrange не работает, т.к. данных очень много), который с помощью скрипта импортирую в другую таблицу, НО! Как задать условие, чтобы скрипт импортировал только те данные, где есть определенный город?

До этого я использовал формулу =query(importrange:"SELECT * Where Col"n"='Название города'")
т.е. он мне выдавал данные интересующего города...

Answer (score 0):

Ваш запрос будет вглядить так:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1rhVd0o0MVim1oK0oOVeQVhkx7NZwXMpqw2yGc6Uy";"ЛИСТ 1!В1:В" );"select * where Col1 contains 'Щучин'")
```

1rhVd0o0MVim1oK0oOVeQVhkx7NZwXMpqw2yGc6Uy - ID Вашего документа откуда берутся данные

Щучин - город

Лист 1 - Ваш лист где находятся данные

В1:В  - Диапозон переносимых данных например В1:С перенесёт еще и значения из колонки С

Будут вопросы пишите